# How to have dynamic width for a group of views in react native?

Tags: android-layout, react-native, flexbox

I am learning React Native and in the process am trying to achieve a layout design which will have 8 *views* in a row whose width should be automatically adjusted based on the width of the device.

I am experimenting with some boilerplate code from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html . With my changes the code looks like this:

```
export default class FlexDirectionBasics extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            // Try setting `flexDirection` to `column`.
            <View>
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
                    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
                    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
                    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
                    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
                    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
                    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
                    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
                    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
};
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to wrap the colour boxes around in two rows but I am not sure how to achieve that.

Thanking you in anticipation
Amby

Answer (score 2):

Use **flex: 0.25** for each small view/block:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'column', height: 120}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', height: 50, top: 100}}>
        <View style={{flex: 0.25,  height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{flex: 0.25,  height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{flex: 0.25,  height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
        <View style={{flex: 0.25,  height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
    </View>

    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', height: 50}}>
    <View style={{flex: 0.25,  height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
        <View style={{flex: 0.25,  height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
        <View style={{flex: 0.25,  height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{flex: 0.25,  height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
    </View>
</View>
```

Live Demo: https://snack.expo.io/SkFLS8-df

Comment: Thanks. This is a better solution! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Just needed to divide the width into 4 equal parts.

I am posting the change only:

```
import { AppRegistry, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const {width} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

And each View's width should be replaced by :

```
width * 0.25
```

Thanks, guys. I need to get the programmer's (rubber) duck!